# JQuery Autocomplete - Http Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, cookies

What is the easiest way to pass along BASIC authentication credentials that are currently stored by the browser in the session cookie when making the `.autocomplete` call? I know that I can use the ajax method with username and password, but I do not know how to retrieve said information from the browser.

Essentially, the user logs in using the htpswd/htaccess functionality of apache, and I know that thr browser must be storing the information in a cookie. My question is how do I retrieve said information to be used in the AJAX call, so that it does not return a 410 response?

My current code:

```
$( ".item" ).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response){$.get("https://www.mydomain.com/blah/bling/blat/", 
                        function(data){response(JSON.parse(data));});},
                        minLength: 2
                    });
```

Comment: It's not stored in a cookie. I don't think JavaScript can access it directly. But I don't think it needs to. If the credentials are needed, the browser will send them automatically, and prompt the user if necessary. See [here](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/access-http-authentication-credentials-via-javascript-696405.html)

Comment: Your current code has a syntax error - missing a ".  Fixed it for you though.

Comment: upon further reflection, @barmar is 100% correct.  you don't need to pass your cred's with every request, although feel free to check out my answer if you need to log in with JS (i.e. custom http auth login form).

Comment: @Barmar You are correct it seems. I don't know why I was getting this issue yesterday, but trying it again today it works fine. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication credentials are not stored in a cookie. I don't think JavaScript can access it directly. But I don't think it needs to. If the credentials are needed, the browser will send them automatically, and prompt the user if necessary. See [here](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/access-http-authentication-credentials-via-javascript-696405.html) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I don't know why this was not the case when I originally tried it.